# Parsing a comment

Tags: java, xslt

I am trying to parse this java comment:

```
/**
 * @parser
 *          path="/helloworld"
 *          href="/helloworld"
 *          
 *
 *
 *          path="/helloworld_2"
 *          href="/helloworld_2"
 *          
 *           
**/
```

I am using the following xsl code to parse it.

```
<span class="nowrap"> path: 
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        //code to output data
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:value-of select="@path"/>
                </a>
            </span>
```

Currently I am getting an output, of just helloworld_2 with the code above.

if I only have the following in the comment

```
/**
 * @parser
 *          path="/helloworld"
 *          href="/helloworld"
 *          
**/
```

I will get the output of helloworld. How can I output both helloworld and helloworld_2 without having helloworld_2 overriding helloworld? Is there a way to loop around this code and have it still save the first helloworld and output it? I tried

```
<xsl:for-each select="@path">
<span class="nowrap"> path: 
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        //code to output data
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:value-of select="@path"/>
                </a>
            </span>

             </xsl:for-each>
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re trying to parse non-XML content with XSL. Why?

`<xsl:value-of select="@path"/>` is intended to operate on something like this:

```
<element path="a path"/>
```

In that case, the value would be `a path`.

You *can* write XSL to parse these strings, but I recommend you find another way, such as parsing the string with Java and then writing XML with [dom4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/) or [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/).

If you’re *really* hung up on using XSL for this, here’s a simple stylesheet that gives an idea of how to proceed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="href" select="substring-before(substring-after(text(), 'href=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="substring-before(substring-after(text(), 'path=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
    <a href="{$href}"><xsl:value-of select="$path" /></a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not too pleasant, as you can see.

When run on this document:

```
<root>
  /**
   * @parser
   *          path="/helloworld"
   *          href="/helloworld"
   *          
  **/
</root>
```

It produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a href="/helloworld">/helloworld</a>
```

If you’re serious about continuing, I’d recommend the more sophisticated technique of writing a [named template](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xslt/8400) that you can call repeatedly to parse out the information you want. Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template name="parse-attribute">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(text(), concat($name, '=&quot;')), '&quot;')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="href"><xsl:call-template name="parse-attribute"><xsl:with-param name="name" select="'href'" /></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="path"><xsl:call-template name="parse-attribute"><xsl:with-param name="name" select="'path'" /></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
    <a href="{$href}"><xsl:value-of select="$path" /></a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: if I were to do it this way, do you have an idea as to how I can make this work?

Comment: First point is that to write a parser you need to know the grammar of what you are parsing. One or two example inputs do not constitute a specification.

Comment: @user3632508: I updated the answer with an example stylesheet.